# Conditional expectation for three variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

I am studying my probability course and came up with the following question:

Let $X, Y, Z$ be three independent geometrically distributed random variables with parameter $p, q, l$ which represents the number of failures before
the first success. In addition, those variables are conditioned by $X+Y+Z=A$. Let $n,m,k \in N$ and such that $n+m+k=B$.
Find
$$
E(X^n\times Y^m\times Z^k|X+Y+Z=A)
$$

I have tried to represent $Z=A-X-Y$ and use nested expectations, but it did not give any results.

I am considering a probability first:

$$
P(X^n\times Y^m\times Z^k|X+Y+Z=A)=\frac{P(X^n\times Y^m\times Z^k)P(X=A-Y-Z)}{P(X+Y+Z=A)}
$$
The denominator can be easily computed, however, I do not know how to compute nominator.

Comment: Same question in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606636/expectation-of-product-under-condition

Comment: Yes, it was closed due to not enough information  provided. I have corrected it and re-posted it--it says that I have an option o repost

Comment: You should have edited the previous post to add the new attempt.

Comment: @volond ,I think  you should  start with $p=q=l$ and then for general case.

Comment: @Masoud: Yes, I have done p=q=l=1 case. It is easy, but, I do not see how to do it when $p=q=l \neq 1$

Comment: You may find it easier to compute $\exp(P(n \ln X + m \ln Y + k \ln (A - X - Y)))$.

Comment: @Eric Towers: Can you please elaborate on it, or write an answer. I am not sure where this $exp$ function is coming from. I.e. why this conditional expectation is equivalent to this function? Thank you

Comment: In the $p=q=l \neq 1$ case, each way of partitioning $A$ into $X+Y+Z$ is equally likely.  E.g. $X=A, Y=Z=0$ is as likely as $X=5, Y=7, Z=A-12$ or whatever.  However, I don't know how to exploit this further to calculate $E[ X^n Y^m Z^k]$ except via exhaustive case listing (even if nested).

Comment: @antkam: would you please write your solution via exhaustive case. It might be different from what I have tried. thank you.